# Why does toggling the Display Out of Stock Products setting trigger design/cache issues?

Tags: magento-enterprise, configuration, error, debugging

**Background**

Our site has used Google Commerce Search for a few years now. That program is being discontinued so now we're moving to Solr in our Enterprise 1.13.0.2 store. A requirement of Solr (that our implementation of GCS did not require) is to have Catalog > Inventory > Display Out of Stock Products turned on if you want to have OOS products listed in search results (we do). Enter, problems.

**When `cataloginventory/options/show_out_of_stock == 1`**

To summarize, weird stuff starts happening that does not happen otherwise. For example, **tons** of max execution time errors:

```
[11-Mar-2014 18:20:46 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 600 seconds
  exceeded in www/app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Processor.php on line 483
[11-Mar-2014 18:25:42 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 600 seconds
  exceeded in www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 0
[11-Mar-2014 20:18:31 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 600 seconds 
  exceeded in www/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/Memcached.php on line 180
```

Memory size errors:

```
[11-Mar-2014 18:26:42 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes
  exhausted (tried to allocate 519577601 bytes) in www/app/Mage.php on line 826
```

*Page Block!* errors:

```
2014-03-11T18:54:17+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: type  in 
  www/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php on line 134
2014-03-11T18:54:17+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: name  in 
  www/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php on line 135
2014-03-11T18:54:17+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Missing argument 1 for 
  Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::addItem()  in 
  www/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php on line 128
2014-03-11T18:54:17+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Missing argument 2 for 
  Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::addItem()  in 
  www/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php on line 128
```

**Question**

Why would changing the display out of stock setting cause these errors?

**BTW**

We've absolutely confirmed that these errors happen only after the setting in question is changed to Yes, clearing cache, and reindexing. And that they do not occur when the setting is changed to No, cache is cleared and reindexed.

Comment: Just to be clear - you can leave the setting untouched (and perhaps change another), clear cache and reindex, and you do not see these errors?

Comment: @benmarks Correct

Answer (score 1):

I can't say why the `max_execution_time` and `memory_size` errors occur. I think it is some bad implementation of some feature which only is used, when the stock is used maybe? These errors are hard to debug. Somewhere is a lot of time and memory wasted and not freed. Happy digging.

But I'm sure that this errors:

> 2014-03-11T18:54:17+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: type 
>   in    www/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php on line 134
>   2014-03-11T18:54:17+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: name 
>   in    www/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php on line 135
>   2014-03-11T18:54:17+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Missing argument 1 for
>   Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::addItem()  in
>   www/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php on line 128
>   2014-03-11T18:54:17+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Missing argument 2 for
>   Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::addItem()  in
>   www/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php on line 128

are not in (direct) connection to the stock, but instead are mistakes maybe in some layout.xml where `<action method="addItem"` is used but the parameters are missing. For this error you need to check where the error occurs and what the stacktrace is.

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::addItem()

is a sign for my theory.

Comment: The XML checks out and the missing parameters do seem to be in direct connection to the setting because the errors disappear/appear with the config change.